# Adding new column to ordered products in osCommerce

Tags: php, mysql, sql, checkout, oscommerce

I have a store using osCommerce with the Dynamo one page checkout addon. I added a new column called "drop_ship_id" to the orders_products table and products table. Under the checkout_process.php file is where I believe the products that the user has ordered, are entered into the orders_products table in the database. I'm trying to pull the drop_ship_id field from each ordered product, and enter it into the orders_products table where I can call on it later on in the checkout process. Here is my current code snip:

```
// initialized for the email confirmation
$products_ordered = '';
$subtotal = 0;
$total_tax = 0;

for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($order->products); $i++) {
  if (!in_array($payment, $suspended_payment)) {
    $checkout->reduce_stock($order->products[$i]);
}

$sql_data_array = array('orders_id' => $insert_id,
                        'products_id' => tep_get_prid($order->products[$i]['id']),
                        'products_model' => $order->products[$i]['model'],
                        'products_name' => $order->products[$i]['name'],
                        'products_price' => $order->products[$i]['price'],
                        'final_price' => $order->products[$i]['final_price'],
                        'products_tax' => $order->products[$i]['tax'],
                        'products_quantity' => $order->products[$i]['qty'],
            'drop_ship_id' => $order->products[$i]['drop_ship_id']);

tep_db_perform($database['ORDERS_PRODUCTS'], $sql_data_array);

$order_products_id = tep_db_insert_id();
```

Not sure if this is where it belongs, but I'm unable to get it to transfer the drop_ship_id field with this code. Does anyone know a good way of getting this to work?

Comment: add `print_r($order->products[$i]);` in loop to check if the data is here

Comment: Only problem is that I wont be able to see whats printed, because this file is only used to process everything within a loading bar

Comment: then add `die();` and use browser's developer tools - you will see the output, our use logging to file

Answer (score 1):

You can use the error log to try and dump some information to the logs:

```
error_log("product id: " . $order->products[$i]['products_id'] . ", dropship order id: " . $order->products[$i]['drop_ship_id']);
```

As to why the value is not being transferred, I would check a few things in `includes/classes/order.php` - when creating a new order, it will copy the values from the cart's list of products. So you should ensure either:

1. the products in the cart contain this field (i.e. this field should be one of the select values in the SQL when the product is retrieved from the database and put into the cart).
2. you add the field in afterwards by explicitly writing the value within `order.php`.

And later on, when loading a saved order from the database, you should ensure you add the `drop_ship_id` to your SQL query.